# How to improve large Vue component performance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm currently doing a form editor (like google forms). It's a vue component, basically looking like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [Array of objects describing form questions]
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="form-editor">
    <!-- some interface not related to a specific question (like creating a new question) -->
    <div v-for="question in questions" :key="question.id">
      <input v-model=question.title>
      <!-- more inputs binded to a specific question properties via v-model -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It works fine, but when the number of questions gets bigger, it experiences huge performance issues. Should i extract logic related to a single question into a separate component to render it in a v-for loop? Or what do i do?

Comment: Maybe you should think about a paging or dynamic loading on scroll?

Comment: How bigger hundreds? If it is less it could probably be because you are updating all the questions when something changes in just one of them, can you show some more code when inputs update data?